# Pytorch custom criterion depending on target

Tags: python, pytorch

Im doing a research project where I want to create a custom loss function depending on the targets. I.e. I want to penalize with `BCEWithLogitsLoss` plus adding a hyperparameter `lambda`. I only want to add this hyperparameter if the model is not correctly detecting a class.

With more detail, I have a pretrained model that I want to retrain freezing some of the layers. This model detects faces in images with some probability. I want to penalize certain kind of images if they are incorrectly classified with a factor lambda (suppose that the images that need that penalization have a special character in the name or so)

From the source code of `pytorch`:

```
import torch.nn.modules.loss as l

class CustomBCEWithLogitsLoss(l._Loss):
    def __init__(self, weight: Optional[Tensor] = None, size_average=None, reduce=None, reduction: str = 'mean',
                 pos_weight: Optional[Tensor] = None) -> None:
        super(BCEWithLogitsLoss, self).__init__(size_average, reduce, reduction)
        self.register_buffer('weight', weight)
        self.register_buffer('pos_weight', pos_weight)
        self.weight: Optional[Tensor]
        self.pos_weight: Optional[Tensor]

    def forward(self, input: Tensor, target: Tensor) -> Tensor:
        return F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(input, target,
                                                  self.weight,
                                                  pos_weight=self.pos_weight,
                                                  reduction=self.reduction)
```

Here, forward has two tensors as inputs, so I dont know how to add here the class of the images that I want to penalize with lambda. Adding lambda to the constructor is ok, but how to do the forward pass if it only allows tensors?

Edit:
To clarify the question, Suppose that I have a training/testing folder with the images. The files with the character `@` in the filename are the ones that I want to classify correctly way more than the files without the character, with a factor `lambda`.

How can I tell in the regular fashion of [training a model in pytorch](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html), that those files have to use a `lambda` penalization (let's say that the loss function is lambda * BCEWithLogitLoss) but the other ones not? I'm using `DataLoader`.

Comment: What do you mean by *"incorrectly classified with a factor lambda"*?

Comment: @Ivan given a image X_i that I want to classify correctly, if the image X_i pertains a certain subset of special inputs (the ones I want to penalize extra if they are not correctly predicted) apply a factor lambda (positive integer) to `binary_cross_entropy_with_logits`. Otherwise, only apply `binary_cross_entropy_with_logits` loss. The special inputs should be labeled in some form, maybe with a special character in the filename. This is also another problem I dont know how to address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom class for your dataset or instead build on top of an existing built-in dataset. For instance, you can use [`datasets.ImageFolder`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder.html) as a base class. The logic added on top is to identify if the filename contains the special token, for example `@` and provide this information in the element returned by `__getitem__`. Looking at the parent [`__getitem__`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/_modules/torchvision/datasets/folder.html#DatasetFolder) function from `datasets.DatasetFolder`, a minimal working implementation could be:

```
class Dataset(datasets.ImageFolder):
    def __init__(self, token, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.token = token
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        path, _ = self.samples[index]      # retrieve path of instance
        match = self.token in path         # determine if there is a match 
        x, y = super().__getitem__(index)  # call parent to get input and label
        return x, int(match), y
```

Each dataset element consists of the input image tensor and a label `0`, or `1` designating whether that input has the `token` in its filename.

```
>>> ds = Dataset(token='@', root='root_to_dataset')
```

Which you would use like any other dataset: with a [`DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader) wrapper

```
>>> dl = DataLoader(ds, batch_size=2)
```

Now when iterating over this daloader, you will have:

```
>>> for x, m, y in dl:
...    # x is the batch of images (b, c, h, w)
...    # m is the batch of {0,1} whether inputs have the pattern in their path (b,)
...    # y is the batch of labels (b,)
```

---

Now that we have this, we need to apply the lambda factor on the loss terms. However, we can't assume here that all elements in a given minibatch will follow the criteria (*i.e.* have the pattern in their filename), therefore we need to handle this element-wise and not in reduced form.

If you take a look at the source file for built-in loss functions [`nn.modules.loss`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/loss.py) you will notice all loss functions are based on a class named `_Loss` which expects a `reduction` parameter. This will be useful for us.

First, consider switching off reduction on your loss function:

```
>>> bce = nn.BCEWithLogitLoss(reduction='none') # provide additional args if necessary
```

Considering we have the mask of "matches" `m` which contains a `1` when the input has the token in their filename, and `0` otherwise. And given a lambda factor `lamb` with which we want to weigh the elements where `m=1`, we can provide the following coefficient to our loss term to perform the desired operation:

```
>>> coeff = lamb*m + 1-m 
# if m=0 => coeff=1; 
# if m=1 => coeff=lamb;
```

---

To apply the loss strategy properly we simple point-wise multiply `coeff` with the unreduced loss term (which is shaped `(b,)`).

```
>>> weighted = coeff*bce_loss
```

All in all, this would look like this:

```
>>> for x, m, y in dl:
...    y_pred = model(x)
...    bce_loss = bce(y_pred, y)
...    coeff = lamb*m + 1-m 
...    bce_weighted = torch.mean(coeff*bce_loss)
...    bce_weighted.backward()
```

Comment: But this answer doesn't explain how the input should be treated. If `x_i` is not detecting a face in an image, I want a factor of lambda extra penalization if the image is from a subset. Otherwise, the normal penalization. How can I distinguish before the forward pass in the training phase if the image is loaded by `datasets.ImageFolder`?

Comment: @Norhther, I have updated my answer with a complete minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for asking. Why did you not make a custom loss function?. you are still restricting yourself to PyTorch's functions; maybe write the custom equation of the loss, and someone will help. (This is not an answer, but I can not leave a comment yet)

Answer (score 0):

Seem like you met a problem with modifying dynamic weight based on the training result. I'm not sure about your formula (the lambda term), let's take the math formula in [pytorch document](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html#torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss), I assume that you want:

`l(xi,yi) = lambda * loss(i) if (xi>0.5==yi) else loss(i) # correct class condition`

If it's incorrect, I think you can easily modify it to adapt to your project

```py
import torch.nn.modules.loss as l
from typing import Optional
from torch import Tensor
from torch.nn import functional as F

class CustomBCEWithLogitsLoss(l._Loss):
    def __init__(self, alpha: float, weight: Optional[Tensor] = None, size_average=None, reduce=None, reduction: str = 'mean',
                 pos_weight: Optional[Tensor] = None) -> None:
        super(CustomBCEWithLogitsLoss, self).__init__(size_average, reduce, reduction)
        self.register_buffer('weight', weight)
        self.register_buffer('pos_weight', pos_weight)
#         self.weight: Optional[Tensor]
        self.pos_weight: Optional[Tensor]
        
        self.alpha = alpha # replace lambda by alpha to avoid the unwanted bug with lambda function
        
    def forward(self, input: Tensor, target: Tensor) -> Tensor:
        reg = torch.ones_like(target, dtype=torch.float32)
        pred = input.ge(0.5).int()
        mask = pred == target
        reg[~mask] *= self.alpha # only apply to correct class
        return F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(input, target,
                                                  weight = reg, # replace weight by alpha
                                                  pos_weight=self.pos_weight,
                                                  reduction=self.reduction)
```

Comment: Not exactly that, see the edit please

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to access filenames using `your_loader.dataset.samples[i]` tuple (assuming `for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(your_loader)` in your training loop and `shuffle=False`) and multiply loss by lambda depending upon it, with the batch size of 1 you wouldn't even need a custom loss function.

An ideal solution would probably require a custom `Dataset` inheriting from `ImageFolder` to return an additional feature in `__getitem__()` and passing it further.